# Re-enabling a disabled submit button

Tags: jquery

I have what seems to be a simple line of jquery, but it's not working as expected.
I am trying to accomplish the following:

1. Disable a button
2. Wait almost a second
3. Enable the same button

Here is the line of code:

```
    $("#formsubmit").prop('disabled',true).delay(750).prop('disabled',false);
```

1 and 2 are accomplished, but 3 never happens
See a (non) working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/03a1nfqt/)

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's `.delay()` function is usually used for queuing effects, not manipulating attributes:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

If you must, you can supply a custom queue, such as shown here:

```js
$("#formsubmit").click(function () {
    $('.message').show();

    var button = $(this);
    button.prop("disabled", true).delay(750).queue(function (next) {
        button.prop("disabled", false);
        next();
    });
});
```

```css
span.message {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="form"> <span class="message">Some Message</span>

    <input type="button" id="formsubmit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Or, you just use the native `setTimeout` function instead.

Answer (score 1):

`.delay()` will not work in this scenario, instead of using `.delay()` use `setTimeout()` as shown:-

```
$("#formsubmit").click(function() {
  $("#formsubmit").prop('disabled',true);
  setTimeout(function(){$("#formsubmit").prop('disabled',false);},750)
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/03a1nfqt/2/)

**Edit :-**

> `.delay()` only delays item(s) in a queue like 
>    animations

so in this case instead of `.dealy()` `setTimeout()` will work.

Comment: I've tried and yes its correct `.delay()` is not working but any reason why its not working ?